# Display multiple Field name in single Textbox

Tags: angularjs

I have multiple set off field name and I want to display all those in single textbox using  ng-model. But I am able to display only single field name.

This is my code : `<p> {{cts.selectedcontact.location.state + " "cts.selectedcontact.location.postcode}} </p>`

```
<input type="text" ng-model="cts.selectedcontact.location.state"+`"cts.selectedcontact.location.postcode"> <br/>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```js
angular.module("app",[]).controller("appContr",function($scope)
{
$scope.newmodelName="";
$scope.Sample1="ram";
$scope.Sample2="esh";

$scope.Concstring=function(val1,val2)
{
return val1+val2;
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appContr">
                    <input type="text" ng-init="newModelName =Concstring(Sample1,Sample2)"  ng-model="newModelName">
                    <br />
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize new variable for text box like as

```
<div ng-init="newField = cts.selectedcontact.location.state + cts.selectedcontact.location.postcode">
<input type="text" ng-model="newField"> <br/>
</div>
```

Comment: I have edited your answer due to your syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

well ng-model shall have only one argument, that will be binded to the field value and it will receive the value of the input field every time it is changed. So you can not use several variables in one ng-model.

But if you would like to show it as a default value, then you can set it in the value argument in html, or just in your js file. like so:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="modelValue"> <br/>
```

and in .js file:

```
$scope.modelValue = $scope.cts.selectedcontact.location.state + $scope.cts.selectedcontact.location.postcode;
```